# NoClassDefFoundError when a method invoked using init() extending HttpServlet on tomcat startup

Tags: tomcat, jersey, noclassdeffounderror, init

I have a Jersey Restful webservice which is running on Tomcat 9.
My requirement is to execute a method periodically every 2 min; for that I have a class called "LoadModels" which extends TimerTask and will run every 2 min when I do the below

```
timer.schedule(new LoadModels(), date.getTime(), 1000 * 2 * 60);
```

I am trying to trigger this this when tomcat starts so that my task executes every 2 min. for that I have written a class which extends HttpServlet and written init() which is invoking perfectly when tomcat starts.

But the problem is as soon I place the

```
timer.schedule(new LoadModels(), date.getTime(), 1000 * 2 * 60);
```

inside the init() method; it thorws

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel

What I understood is; when tomcat first started; it is trying to invoke init() method; but that is linked with some jars which are not being loaded at that moment.

How to solve this issue. I am pasting the code below.

```
  public class InitializeListner extends HttpServlet {
       public void init() {
        System.out.println(" INIT METHOD START");
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        timer.schedule(new LoadModels(), date.getTime(), 1000 * 10* 60);
        System.out.println(" INIT METHOD END");
        }
       }
```

my Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>FlightAvailabilityPredictor</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.travelport.h2o.availabilitypredictor</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitializeListner</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.travelport.h2o.availabilitypredictor.listener.InitializeListner</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Below is the Exception:-

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
 INIT METHOD START
Feb 21, 2018 7:18:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hex/genmodel/GenModel
    at com.travelport.h2o.availabilitypredictor.listener.InitializeListner.init(InitializeListner.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:980)
```

Let me know how to resolve this..
Thank you all in advance